# Java Conflict with postgresql driver

Tags: java, jboss, postgresql-9.4

I'm experiencing a problem when I try to use Postgresql class.

```
Array res = rs.getArray(fieldName);
Object[] pgArray = (Object[]) res.getArray();
PGobject ob = (PGobject) pgArray[0];
```

The column identified as fieldName is an array of Postgresql Composite type. I've loaded the Postgresql driver in my application server (JBOSS EAP 7) and the same version library is listed in my pom.xml file.

When I execute the code listed above i get a ClassCastException org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to org.postgresql.util.PGobject.

I found that the PGObject object from the ResultSet is from the Application Server Library. The PGObject class in third line is from my Application libraries.

I tried to indicate as provided that library in my Pom, but I get that the class could not be resolved.

Is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Michele

Comment: If your connection is supplied by JBoss, then JBoss also had a PostgreSQL JDBC driver, which means that you should not ship the driver with your code. Change your POM to list the PostgreSQL JDBC driver as `provided`, i.e. need for compilation, but not deployed with app, since it will be "provided" by JBoss.

Comment: I've already tried to list the library as provided in pom, but in that case the class could not be resolved :(.

Comment: how did you install the driver? I recommend installing it as a module, and declare it in your standalone.xml.. then, add the dependency to the module in your MANIFEST.MF that belongs to your app. Also, like @Andreas said, make sure your driver dependency is scope provided